# Selecting last version of entry in different language from sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there any way to do this in one sql query? I would like to get the newest (version) of the same entry in every language available.

My table and example data is:

```
ID  |  Index  |  Version  |  Language  | ...
------------------------------------------------
1        1          1            1         test1
2        1          2            1         test2
3        2          1            1         test3
4        2          1            2         test4
5        2          1            3         test5
6        2          2            3         test6
7        3          1            1         test7
8        3          1            2         test8
```

- ID is unique identifer
- Index is unique for any entry in database which means that all time versions and language version of the same article/entry share the same Index.
- Version is obviously version number. 1 is the first version and any greater number is usually newer.
- Language is the number of language version of entry/article.

I really can't think of way to get this in one query. But maybe it's feasible?

I would like to get something like this:

```
ID  |  Index  |  Version  |  Language  | ...
------------------------------------------------
2        1          2            1         test2
3        2          1            1         test3
4        2          1            2         test4
6        2          2            3         test6
7        3          1            1         test7
8        3          1            2         test8
```

test1 is out because test2 is in the same language and it's newer
test5 is out because test6 is newer in the same language

### Resolved

```
SELECT T1.* FROM entry_view T1 
LEFT JOIN entry_view T2 ON (T1.version < T2.version AND T1.id_language = T2.id_language AND T1.`index` = T2.`index`)
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: see some other questions tagged with `greatest-n-per-group` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    SELECT T1.ID, T1.Index, T1.Version, T1.Language FROM Table T1 
LEFT JOIN Table T2 ON (T1.ID < T2.ID AND T1.Language = T2.Language) 
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Edit: i assumed the IDs were increasing and the newest one would be the last.

maybe try this:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Index, T1.Version, T1.Language FROM Table T1 
LEFT JOIN Table T2 ON (T1.Version < T2.Version AND T1.Language = T2.Language)
 WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: +1. Nice trick to avoid using the aggregates. The second one seems to be more fitting indeed.

Comment: Yes, i learnt this here on SO! - i beleive this is a much faster solution

Comment: Is it impossible to create view from this? It would be useful.

Comment: @Simon: Faster or not, I prefer yours to mine.

Comment: I used second query because I can actually make it into view while I cannot use `Andriy M` solution because there can't be subquery in view

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM atable t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      Index,
      MAX(Version) AS MaxVersion,
      Language
    FROM atable
    GROUP BY Index, Language    
  ) max ON t.Index = max.Index AND t.Version = max.MaxVersion
    AND t.Language = max.Language
```

Comment: Which one would be faster? INNER join or LEFT join ?

Comment: @Kaminari: As a general question, it is too broad to answer definitely, I believe. Speaking of this particular solution, it's not a question of which would be faster, but rather which would bring the correct result. `LEFT JOIN` in this case would return all the rows from your table, which is not what you need, as far as I can understand.

Comment: I was trying to create view which would shorten my queries. Most of the time I will be needing only the newest version of article but it seems that I can't use JOIN in view :(

Comment: @Kaminari: The subquery in my solution returns the last version number of every translation of every `Index` item. You could use that as a view. Of course, it would be much better if it returned the complete rows, together with `ID` and the text part. Still it would allow you to shorten your queries to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

And what about

`SELECT S.* 
FROM (
    SELECT T1.*
    FROM entry_view T1 
    ORDER BY T1.version DESC
    ) S
GROUP BY language`